# List of all currently open profiles

Tags: firefox-addon, user-profile

I'm trying to get a list of currently open profiles. This code below lists alll profiles regardless of open:

```
var tps = Cc['@mozilla.org/toolkit/profile-service;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIToolkitProfileService); //toolkitProfileService

var profileList = tps.profiles;
     while (profileList.hasMoreElements()) {
       var profile = profileList.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIToolkitProfile);
         console.info(profile)
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to lock each profile. If already in use will throw `NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED`

```js
var inUse;
try{
  var profunlock = profile.lock(null);
  inUse = false;
  profunlock.unlock();
}
catch(e){
  inUse = true;
}
```

Comment: Ah great idea, however is this locking proces sync? Or async? Or is it sync but super fast?

Comment: I updated the answer with the relative snippet. It's synchronous operation but I don't see why it would be expensive.

Comment: Cool thanks very much man!! :) How come we don't test if e is ns_error_file_access_denied, how would we do this? would we do `e.name == 'ns_error_file_access_denied'`?

Comment: This lock/unlock solution does seem like a hack, as we have to run an unlock function after. Still open to other solutions :) but i accepted your answer thanks man

Comment: It's not a hack, that how every Gecko app detects if the profile is already in use. As for the exception code, `e.result == Components.results.NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED`